# How to check programmatically if iCloud Drive is activated

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, icloud

Is there a way to check in OS X and IOS if the user has iCloud Drive activated ? Not The Documents and Data option, but the new iCloud Drive ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use iCloud in your app, [you'll need to get to know CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Not only does your user need to have iCloud enabled, but they also need to grant permission for your application to access files in iCloud.

And to find out if that permission has been granted (or is even possible), the API you're likely to need most is in CloudKit:

[`accountStatusWithCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:) which includes these account status results:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger  {
   CKAccountStatusCouldNotDetermine  = 0,
   CKAccountStatusAvailable  = 1,
   CKAccountStatusRestricted  = 2,
   CKAccountStatusNoAccount  = 3,
} CKAccountStatus;
```

This API is only available with iOS 8 and MacOS 10.10 (Yosemite) and newer.